# JSON.Stringify Adds Quotes To ID

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js, stringify

I'm using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to edit my JSON file based on changes to an online database. Everything works right, except it is making quotes around a number which is screwing up the JSON file. For example it should be `"id": 1` but it is printing out `"id": "1"`. How would I edit the quotes out? I prefer to use JSON.stringify and not an alternative.

Comment: try converting the string to an int before outputting the results http://us2.php.net/intval

Comment: Are you certain the value of `1` remains a `Number` throughout the entire process? For the editing, an `<input>`'s `.value` property only holds `String`s and will type-cast any values set to it.

Comment: Hmm, you asked this question twice, the second around 40 minutes after this one! Please don't do this - it duplicates work for people. I've voted to close this one as a duplicate of the other, as there is more detail on the other one.

Answer (score 3):

if you are getting the number from input field, the number or whatever input is always string and therefore its quoted.

To fix that you should add parseInt() for your input values like:

```
var value = parseInt($('#fieldID').val());
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But the id field is not editable. There is no input.

Comment: what are you stringifing ?.

Comment: The changes to the database:   `Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
           this.on("change", function (model, options) {
             data1 = JSON.stringify(this); 
             obj = JSON.parse(data1);
             $.ajax({url:"testingphp.php",type:"POST",data:{
               "data3":obj
            }});`

Comment: You have to show how you're defining `{id}`.

Comment: this.on("change", function (model, options) { data1 = JSON.stringify(this); You are stringifying a a form or a field.

Comment: I'm stringifying the changes made to the database.

Comment: Without know what "this" is i cant help you much. i dont know what it contains and this is the item you are stringifying

Comment: `Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
           this.on("change", function (model, options) {
             data1 = JSON.stringify(this); 
             obj = JSON.parse(data1);
             $.ajax({url:"testingphp.php",type:"POST",data:{
               "data3":obj
            }});
            if (options && options.save === false) return;
            });
          }
        });`

Comment: i am not backbone savvy and dont want to give you false information, however if you could console.log "this" and see what this object look like and manually convert it to int it might work

Answer (score 0):

`1` must not be a true integer to begin with. Executing `JSON.stringify({id: 1})` in the console will return `"{"id":1}"`. How are you defining the value for `id`? I'm guessing at that point, it is getting saved as a string (i.e. `{id: "1"}`).

Comment: `var columns = [{
        name: "id", // The key of the model attribute
        label: "ID", // The name to display in the header
        editable: false`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear there. I'm wondering how you assign a value to the `id` property of the object you're `JSON.stringify`'ing. So you have: `[{name: "id", label: "ID", editable: false}]`, but where does the `id` property get assigned a value?

Comment: It's already assigned a value in the JSON value.

Comment: By what it looks its seems he is strinfiging a <select> or maybe some other object

Comment: I'm just trying to update it.

Comment: If you're referring the Backbone model (which I think you are, now that UI see your comment above: `JSON.stringify(this)`), the id attribute will be a string. See [Backbone documentation on model id](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id)

Comment: @AnalogWeapon Yes, thank you. How can I make it not a string?

Comment: My experience with Backbone models isn't as strong as many others here, but I believe you would have to use [`idAttribute` when the model is defined](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute).

Comment: I'm fairly certain you've narrowed it down here, but my experience with Backbone models doesn't qualify me to answer this as much as someone else. You might want to search / make a new question about getting Backbone model id's to be integer.