# BackboneJS Make ID Integer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, backbone.js

I'm using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to edit my JSON file based on changes to an online database. Everything works right, except it is making quotes around a number which is screwing up the JSON file. For example it should be `"id": 1` but it is printing out `"id": "1"`. How would I edit the quotes out? I prefer to use JSON.stringify and not an alternative.

Here is where I'm stringifying it and using BackboneJS:

```
var Territories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Territory,
  url: "examples/olympics.json",
  initialize: function () {
    Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.on("change", function (model, options) {
      var data1 = JSON.stringify(this); 
      obj = JSON.parse(data1);
      $.ajax({url:"testingphp.php",type:"POST",data:{
        "data3":obj
      }
    });
    if (options && options.save === false) return;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is this JSON? Where does the JSON come from? Where is the problematic part? This almost certainly isn't a Backbone issue so much as a problem with the initial data that gets turned into JSON.

Comment: I agree with @MattBall, it is likely that what you think is an integer is actually a string to begin with. Basically, when you create the object you are probably creating it with a string instead of a number.

Comment: The JSON is a different file. It starts out like this `{"id": 1, "city": "Rio de Janeiro", "country": "Brazil", "year": "2016", "type": "Summer", "url": "http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/27/1783/full/ermbydegexxjuvv9fec3upvaw.gif"}` and ends up like this `{"id": "1", "city": "Rio de Janeiro", "country": "Brazil", "year": "2016", "type": "Summer", "url": "http://content.sportslogos.net/logos/27/1783/full/ermbydegexxjuvv9fec3upvaw.gif"}`

Comment: Okay, how does it end up like that?

Comment: If I change a cell, then it updates that using PHP: `<?php $jsonString = file_get_contents('examples/olympics.json');
        $data = json_decode($jsonString,true); 
        $data3 = $_REQUEST ["data3"];
        $data = $data3;
        $newJsonString = json_encode($data);
        file_put_contents('examples/olympics.json', $newJsonString); 
        ?>`

Comment: Other answers to this question [on its duplicate here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890681/json-stringify-adds-quotes-to-id) - I'm voting to close the other, as there is less detail generally on that one.